# how to take an ipaddress as a input in python

Tags: python-2.7, os.system

While doing this it gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Desktop\app.py", line 23, in <module>
       a=input("enter the ipaddress")
     File "<string>", line 1
       192.168.1.1
               ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's my code:

```
import os
a=input("enter the ipaddress")
os.system('a')


it does not work help me out !!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the string 'a' not the variable `a`, take the quotation marks off:

```
import os
a=input("enter the ipaddress")
os.system(a)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Desktop\app.py", line 22, in <module>
    z=input("")
  File "<string>", line 1
    192.168.1.1
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `hostname` instead of `a`, because as you will run some commands after ssh to some device, the input should get assigned as `hostname` -  `ssh.connect(hostname, port=22, username=x, password=y)`. So the suggested code is -

```
import os
hostname=input("enter the ipaddress")
os.system(hostname)
```